# Is it possible to write organic chemical substance in inline math mode?

Tags: math-mode, chemfig, chemistry, inline

Is it possible to write organic chemical substance in inline math mode?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, is possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\begin{document} 
%
\[
\psi = \psi(
\chemfig{*6([,.2]-=-=-=)}
)  + \psi
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]